¿Como eliminar ese pequeño puntito?
estoy diseñando un sitio en ASP.net con bootstrap y la verdad que no soy muy bueno para ello, tengo este codigo de aqui abajo:
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div id="PeliculasList" class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span class="badge p-2 ms-1 mb-1 align-items-center w-auto text-bg-success rounded-pill">
        <span class="px-1">A Beautiful Mind</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DownPelicula('A Beautiful Mind')">
          <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Down-circle"></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DeletePelicula('A Beautiful Mind')">
          <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#x-circle-fill"></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="p-0"></div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span class="badge p-2 ms-1 mb-1 align-items-center text-bg-success bg-opacity-75 rounded-pill">
        <span class="px-1">The Dark Knight Rises</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="UpPelicula('The Dark Knight Rises')">
          <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Up-circle"></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DownPelicula('The Dark Knight Rises')">
          <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Down-circle"></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DeletePelicula('The Dark Knight Rises')">
          <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#x-circle-fill"></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="p-0"></div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span class="badge p-2 ms-1 mb-1 align-items-center text-bg-success bg-opacity-50 rounded-pill">
        <span class="px-1">A Clockwork Orange</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="UpPelicula('A Clockwork Orange')">
          <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Up-circle"></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DeletePelicula('A Clockwork Orange')">
          <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#x-circle-fill"></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span class="badge p-2 ms-1 mb-1 align-items-center text-bg-success bg-opacity-50 rounded-pill">
        <span class="px-1">Indiana Jones: Raiders of the Lost Ark</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="UpPelicula('Indiana Jones: Raiders of the Lost Ark')">
          <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Up-circle"></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DeletePelicula('Indiana Jones: Raiders of the Lost Ark')">
          <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#x-circle-fill"></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="p-0"></div>
    <div class="p-0"></div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span class="badge p-2 ms-1 mb-1 align-items-center text-bg-danger bg-opacity-75 rounded-pill">
        <span class="px-1">Avengers: Endgame</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DownPelicula('Avengers: Endgame')">
          <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Down-circle"></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="UpPelicula('Avengers: Endgame')">
          <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Up-circle"></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DeletePelicula('Avengers: Endgame')">
          <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#x-circle-fill"></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

El problema es que sale un pequeño puntito al lado de los botones de arriba y abajo pero no en el boton de eliminar y eso que es practicamente el mismo codigo, dejo el link de la imagen:
Imagen
Es un tanto dificil de ver ya que es un punto muy pequeño, es mas no estoy seguro si en todos los monitores se notara, pero yo tengo dos monitores uno de 24" y otro de 27" y en los dos se nota con total claridad, bueno sin mas que decir
Como puedo sacar el puntito??
Desde ya muchas gracias.

¿Podrías colocar la imagen y las hojas de estilo CSS?

[es.so] incorpora en el editor un botón para subir imágenes. Recuerda que los enlaces externos pueden caer, por lo que puede que la imagen que has enlazado ya no esté disponible más adelante.

Parece que está interpretando un espaciado indeseado dentro las etiquetas <a href="xyz">...</a>, más precisamente en estos cierres:
      ...
      </svg>
    </a>

Una forma fácil de dar con estos problemas es usar el inspector de las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador. Siempre que diseñes algo web úsalo.
Puedes eliminar el espaciado ...</svg></a>, o aplicar algún estilo para que no sea visible.

Los "puntitos" que ves son, en realidad, un subrayado de línea punteada que es el estilo predeterminado de los enlaces ( etiqueta A). Y son visibles sólo en el caracter espacio que queda entre las etiquetas.
Para que no aparezcan tenes varias alternativas:

la mas simple es quitarle la decoración a todos los enlaces



a {
  text-decoration: none!important;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div id="PeliculasList" class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span class="badge p-2 ms-1 mb-1 align-items-center w-auto text-bg-success rounded-pill">
        <span class="px-1">A Beautiful Mind</span>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DownPelicula('A Beautiful Mind')">
        <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Down-circle"></use>
          </svg>
      </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DeletePelicula('A Beautiful Mind')">
        <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#x-circle-fill"></use>
          </svg>
      </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="p-0"></div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span class="badge p-2 ms-1 mb-1 align-items-center text-bg-success bg-opacity-75 rounded-pill">
        <span class="px-1">The Dark Knight Rises</span>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="UpPelicula('The Dark Knight Rises')">
        <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Up-circle"></use>
          </svg>
      </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DownPelicula('The Dark Knight Rises')">
        <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Down-circle"></use>
          </svg>
      </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DeletePelicula('The Dark Knight Rises')">
        <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#x-circle-fill"></use>
          </svg>
      </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="p-0"></div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span class="badge p-2 ms-1 mb-1 align-items-center text-bg-success bg-opacity-50 rounded-pill">
        <span class="px-1">A Clockwork Orange</span>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="UpPelicula('A Clockwork Orange')">
        <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Up-circle"></use>
          </svg>
      </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DeletePelicula('A Clockwork Orange')">
        <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#x-circle-fill"></use>
          </svg>
      </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span class="badge p-2 ms-1 mb-1 align-items-center text-bg-success bg-opacity-50 rounded-pill">
        <span class="px-1">Indiana Jones: Raiders of the Lost Ark</span>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="UpPelicula('Indiana Jones: Raiders of the Lost Ark')">
        <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Up-circle"></use>
          </svg>
      </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DeletePelicula('Indiana Jones: Raiders of the Lost Ark')">
        <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#x-circle-fill"></use>
          </svg>
      </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="p-0"></div>
    <div class="p-0"></div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span class="badge p-2 ms-1 mb-1 align-items-center text-bg-danger bg-opacity-75 rounded-pill">
        <span class="px-1">Avengers: Endgame</span>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DownPelicula('Avengers: Endgame')">
        <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Down-circle"></use>
          </svg>
      </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="UpPelicula('Avengers: Endgame')">
        <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#Up-circle"></use>
          </svg>
      </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DeletePelicula('Avengers: Endgame')">
        <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#x-circle-fill"></use>
          </svg>
      </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<svg id="icon-symbols" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">

<symbol id="icon-share" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path
      d="M19.3 14.7a4.7 4.7 0 0 0-3.8 2l-6.5-3a4.6 4.6 0 0 0 0-3.4l6.5-3a4.7 4.7 0 1 0-.8-2.6 4.6 4.6 0 0 0 0 .8l-6.9 3a4.7 4.7 0 1 0 0 7l7 3a4.7 4.7 0 0 0-.1.8 4.7 4.7 0 1 0 4.6-4.6Zm0-12.7a2.7 2.7 0 1 1-2.6 2.7A2.7 2.7 0 0 1 19.3 2ZM4.7 14.7A2.7 2.7 0 1 1 7.3 12a2.7 2.7 0 0 1-2.6 2.7ZM19.3 22a2.7 2.7 0 1 1 2.7-2.7 2.7 2.7 0 0 1-2.7 2.7Z" />
  </symbol>
  
  <symbol id="Down-circle" viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <g>
      <use href="#icon-share" />
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="Up-circle" viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <g>
      <use href="#icon-share" />
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="x-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <g>
      <use href="#icon-share" />
    </g>
  </symbol>
  
  </svg>




sin embargo para no afectar otros enlaces o etiquetas A lo recomendable es usar una clase y aplicarla a todos los botones o etiquetas A que contienen sólo un svg.



a.botonito {
  text-decoration: none!important;
}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="col-auto">
  <span class="badge p-2 ms-1 mb-1 align-items-center text-bg-danger bg-opacity-75 rounded-pill">
            <span class="px-1">Avengers: Endgame</span>
  <a class="botonito" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DownPelicula('Avengers: Endgame')">
    <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
                <use xlink:href="#Down-circle"></use>
              </svg>
  </a>
  <a class="botonito" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="UpPelicula('Avengers: Endgame')">
    <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
                <use xlink:href="#Up-circle"></use>
              </svg>
  </a>
  <a class="botonito" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DeletePelicula('Avengers: Endgame')">
    <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
                <use xlink:href="#x-circle-fill"></use>
              </svg>
  </a>
  </span>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<svg id="icon-symbols" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">

    <symbol id="icon-share" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path
          d="M19.3 14.7a4.7 4.7 0 0 0-3.8 2l-6.5-3a4.6 4.6 0 0 0 0-3.4l6.5-3a4.7 4.7 0 1 0-.8-2.6 4.6 4.6 0 0 0 0 .8l-6.9 3a4.7 4.7 0 1 0 0 7l7 3a4.7 4.7 0 0 0-.1.8 4.7 4.7 0 1 0 4.6-4.6Zm0-12.7a2.7 2.7 0 1 1-2.6 2.7A2.7 2.7 0 0 1 19.3 2ZM4.7 14.7A2.7 2.7 0 1 1 7.3 12a2.7 2.7 0 0 1-2.6 2.7ZM19.3 22a2.7 2.7 0 1 1 2.7-2.7 2.7 2.7 0 0 1-2.7 2.7Z" />
      </symbol>
      
      <symbol id="Down-circle" viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <g>
          <use href="#icon-share" />
        </g>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="Up-circle" viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <g>
          <use href="#icon-share" />
        </g>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="x-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <g>
          <use href="#icon-share" />
        </g>
      </symbol>
      
      </svg>




ya que estas usando bootstrap, podes usar la clases provistas por el framework para esconder el subrayado

class="link-underline link-underline-opacity-0"



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="col-auto">
  <span class="badge p-2 ms-1 mb-1 align-items-center text-bg-danger bg-opacity-75 rounded-pill">
            <span class="px-1">Avengers: Endgame</span>
  <a class="link-underline link-underline-opacity-0" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DownPelicula('Avengers: Endgame')">
    <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
                <use xlink:href="#Down-circle"></use>
              </svg>
  </a>
  <a class="link-underline link-underline-opacity-0" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="UpPelicula('Avengers: Endgame')">
    <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
                <use xlink:href="#Up-circle"></use>
              </svg>
  </a>
  <a class="link-underline link-underline-opacity-0" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DeletePelicula('Avengers: Endgame')">
    <svg class="bi ms-1" width="16" height="16">
                <use xlink:href="#x-circle-fill"></use>
              </svg>
  </a>
  </span>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<svg id="icon-symbols" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">

    <symbol id="icon-share" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path
          d="M19.3 14.7a4.7 4.7 0 0 0-3.8 2l-6.5-3a4.6 4.6 0 0 0 0-3.4l6.5-3a4.7 4.7 0 1 0-.8-2.6 4.6 4.6 0 0 0 0 .8l-6.9 3a4.7 4.7 0 1 0 0 7l7 3a4.7 4.7 0 0 0-.1.8 4.7 4.7 0 1 0 4.6-4.6Zm0-12.7a2.7 2.7 0 1 1-2.6 2.7A2.7 2.7 0 0 1 19.3 2ZM4.7 14.7A2.7 2.7 0 1 1 7.3 12a2.7 2.7 0 0 1-2.6 2.7ZM19.3 22a2.7 2.7 0 1 1 2.7-2.7 2.7 2.7 0 0 1-2.7 2.7Z" />
      </symbol>
      
      <symbol id="Down-circle" viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <g>
          <use href="#icon-share" />
        </g>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="Up-circle" viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <g>
          <use href="#icon-share" />
        </g>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="x-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <g>
          <use href="#icon-share" />
        </g>
      </symbol>
      
      </svg>




class="link-underline link-underline-opacity-0" me funciono, muchas gracias :-)
